# Passing serialized form data to my (Laravel) controller

Tags: php, serialization, laravel, jquery-ui-sortable, laravel-3

I have a form that asks the user to make 10 game picks and then sort the picks based on confidence.  I'm using jQuery's sortable function and then populating a hidden form element (order-array) with a serialized string on each update to the order.  My problem is how to deal with this array of serialized data in my controller after submission so I can store it (plus the actual game picks) into my database.

#### My Form View

```
{{ Form::open() }}
    <h1>Games for Week {{ $weeknum }} </h1>
    <h3>Visitors @ Hometeam</h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="order-array" id="order-array" value="">
    <ul id="gamelist">
        <?php $count = 1; ?>
        @foreach($games as $game)
            <li class="game-rank" id="c_{{ $count }}">
                <input type="radio" name="{{ "pick_".$game->id }}" value="{{ $game->visitor }}"> 
                {{ $game->visitor }} @ 
                <input type="radio" name="{{ "pick_".$game->id }}" value="{{ $game->hometeam }}">
                {{ $game->hometeam }}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ "game_".$count }}" value="{{ $game->id }}">
            </li>
            <?php $count++; ?>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
        @if(Auth::check())
            {{ Form::hidden('player', $player) }}
            {{ Form::submit('Submit Picks', array('class' => 'link-button')) }}
        @endif
{{ Form::close() }}
```

#### The serialized confidence data being passed to the controller

```
 "c[]=1&c[]=3&c[]=9&c[]=4&c[]=5&c[]=6&c[]=2&c[]=7&c[]=8&c[]=10"
```

#### My controller function

```
public function post_new()
{
    $confidence = Input::get('order-array'); 

    for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
        $array_index = $i-1;

        $pick = new Pick;
        $pick->user_id = Input::get('player');
        $pick->game_id = Input::get("game_$i");  // game number
        $pick->pick = Input::get("pick_$i");  // teamname
        $pick->confidence = $confidence[$array_index];

        $pick->save();
    }
    return Redirect::to ('users');
}
```

Everything works except for the confidence data. What adjustments do I need to make to my controller?
Thanks!!

Comment: Of course! It's always something simple and I get it as soon as I hit the submit button on my question.  I simply use the php explode function in my controller to break it apart.  Being inside the Laravel framework sometimes throws me off.